# How to commit new file to Subversion programmatically?

Tags: java, svn, commit, subclipse

I programmatically checkout project from repository on start of my plugin but i want to add new xml file to this project and commit project with this file.
But this file is not under version control.
I try to use org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.commands.CheckinResourcesCommand but it not work.
Any suggestions?
thanks a lot

Comment: "It doesn't work" says nothing. What doesn't work? You get an error? If so, which one. With full stacktrace. Did you try to Google that error? Likely you are not the first person to run into this problem.

Comment: commit -m "" C:/Work/WorkspaceRCP/runtime-EclipseApplication/***/changeLog.xml
    Illegal target for the requested operation
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: 'C:\Work\WorkspaceRCP\***\changeLog.xml' is not under version control
I tried to find some solution for this but unsuccessfully. I simply need to commit new file to project.

Comment: You can use SVNKit too, it is very easy to use and very well documented, take a look at http://wiki.svnkit.com/Committing_To_A_Repository and samples http://evverythingatonce.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/svn-integration-using-svnkit.html

Comment: @vzamanillo thank you ,I tried SVNKit now and it seems to do the work, but there is another problem. I don't want to ask authentication data from user again. I gave it once for subclipse and eclipse save it. Is there any way to use this data?

Comment: Try using the SVNKit Adapter for Subclipse, go to preferences->SVN and set the client to "SVNKit", additional info about how Subclipse store the user credentials https://www.orcaware.com/svn/wiki/Managing_users_and_passwords

Answer (score 0):

Just as when using the command line client, before a file can be committed it must be "add"ed to Version Control.  So if this is an unversioned file, you first need to run svn add and then you can run svn commit.  So if you are doing this via the Subclipse classes, you would need to run the one for Add before you do Commit.